# Why does Cloth Simulation get Weird?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation, collision

I want to create a cloth simulation, but when I play the simulation the cloth get weird sim....

[image]

I have attached here the .blend file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ho85NoAc5oCJfID6kPSpt_o9BEMg_iIW/view?usp=sharing

How to create a cloth simulation as close to reality as possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give a *Subdivision Surface* modifier to your bowl with a level of 2, put it above the *Cloth* modifier, or apply it, in order to give a denser topology to the collision object:

[image]

If it still looks too jagged, increase the cloth quality steps (in the physics tab) or add a subdivision surface modifier above the cloth modifier on the cloth object.

Comment: This is the most satisfying blender cloth simulation I have seen in my life.

Comment: it takes a lot of practice, I throw my handkerchief on a bowl at least 100 times a day

Comment: hahahahahahha :D

Comment: interesting answer. but what is the explanation to this? why can't i have a low poly object interact with a high poly cloth?

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Yeah you're right; I originally thought that the cloth should have subdivisions would be enough

Comment: @Harry McKenzie maybe because a denser topology helps the faces to not intersect?

Comment: probably. well it works XD

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Since it's a simulation, a higher polycount helps Blender to calculate more accurate how the objects should interact with each other - and this applies to cloth objects as well as collision objects.